# constraints when dynamically loading a shared object from another shared object?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm dynamically loading (whith `dlopen()`) a shared object (named `libprofile1.so`) from `main`.

In `libprofile1.so` I have defined factory function `CreateProfile` and class `Profile`. `CreateProfile` function creates an instance of `Profile` class and returns a pointer to it.  Class `Profile` has a method `pMethod`.

In main, after loading `libprofile1.so`, I'm calling `CreateProfile` method which returns the pointer to the object of `Profile` class (call it `p`).
Afterwards, I'm calling `pMethod` method against object `p` (`p->pMethod`). In this method I'm dynamically loading other shared object (`libdatasources.so`).

In this shared object I have a factory function `CreateDataSource`and class `DataSource`.
`CreateDataSource` function creates an instance of `DataSource` class and returns a pointer to it. `DataSource` class has method `dsMethod`.

As you can notice, structures of both shared objects are similar.

From `pMethod` after loading `libdatasources.so` I'm calling `CreateDataSource` method, which returns me a pointer to an instance of `DataSource` class, call it `ds`.
Then I'm calling `dsMethod` of `ds` object
(`ds->dsMethod`).

---

Now, the problem is following.

When I try to call `dsMethod` of `ds` object, shared object that I'm first loading (`libprofile1.so`) doesn't load. Actually `dlopen()` returns `NULL`. When I read `dlerror` after `dlopen` I get:

`./libprofile1.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18DataSource13dsMethod`

So if I have a call `ds->Method`, than first shared object doesn't load!
If I comment out call `ds->dsMethod` from the source, then my `libprofile1.so` and `libdatasources.so` are loaded without any problems.
I don't see the connection between the call of a method from the second SO, with loading first SO???

Maybe I don't know, but are there any constraints when dynamically loading a shared object, from a shared object that's also been dynamically loaded?

Btw, `dlopen` is used with `RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL`. I tried with `RTLD_LAZY`, but still the same problem.

**UPDATE:**

Libraries are built in Eclipse. Options for G++ compiler and linker are the same for both libraries.
Here are G++ compiler:

```
-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

and G++ linker:

```
-shared
```

options, pasted from `Project Properties -> Settings -> Tool Settings`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question indicating how libprofile1.so and libdataresources.so are built?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dynamically load a DLL you must make sure that it has no unresolved symbols.

The easiest way to do this is to link it against the other DLLs that it needs so that they load automatically rather than you having to load and resolve all dependencies manually.

So if `libprofile1` always uses `libdatasources` make sure they are linked with each other.

If you must do it manually then reverse the order that you load the libraries. So that when you load `libprofile1` the functions that it needs have already been loaded.

Comment: What if the library was already linked with main? I'm finding that if I link my dlopened lib with other libs that are also liked with main that I get multiple copies of them  when the .so is loaded, eg. global vars appear twice. If I don't link my dlopended library with the shared lib I get link errors at runtime because it can't find hte symbols. There must be an easy way to resolve this.
I think I need something like the RTLD_GLOBAL flag for the main application

Comment: Opps, nevermind. I just needed to add the -rdynamic linker flag to my main link step. Resolved everything.

Answer (score 4):

As Martin York pointed out, that's the way it works in Linux. When linking against a library, you have to link to all dependencies, too. That's different in Windows, DLLs take care of their dependencies themselves. When dynamically loading a library that has another library as a dependency, you need to load that library first with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag. This is pretty awkard, imho, since you may not be able to know which dependencies another shared objects requires, or the dependencies can change with a newer version that's otherwise binary compatible. From what I know (and from reading the g++ and ld manpages), it is not possible to create a behaviour similar to Windows' DLLs.
Here's a little testcase:

two.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
   void bar()
   {
      std::cout << "bar()\n";
   }
}
```

one.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
   void bar();

   void foo()
   {
      std::cout << "foo()\n";
      bar ();
   }
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using namespace std;
//       void *libtwo = dlopen("./libtwo.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
   void *libone = dlopen("./libone.so", RTLD_NOW);
   if (!libone)
   {
      cout << "dlopen(libone.so) failed: " << dlerror() << "\n";
      return 1;
   }
   typedef void (*foo_t)();
   foo_t foo = reinterpret_cast<foo_t>(dlsym(libone, "foo"));
   if (!foo)
   {
      cout << "dlsym(libone.so, foo) failed\n";
      return 2;
   }
}
```

one.cpp is compiled into `libone.so` and two.cpp in `libtwo.so`, test.cpp is compiled into the `test` binary.
This will fail and only succeed when the commented line is uncommented.

Comment: quite similar example, but the thing is that in `foo()` i'm loading `libtwo.so` and then getting the function pointer to `bar()`, which I call from `foo()` also.
I'm using a workaround for this problem with a wrapper function `barWrap()` for `bar()`. `barWrap()` is not the part of the class that I'm using (`DataSource`),but rather exported independent function . From this function I'm calling `bar()` (in my case `ds->dsMethod`) and it works fine. By the way I used `RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL` as the argument of `dlopen` but still nothing. Quite a weird problem, I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: Are you linking libone.so against libtwo.so (-ltwo for the linker)? dlopen() should then have no problem loading this. I'll add my gcc command lines as a new comment.

Comment: $ g++ -shared -fpic -o libtwo.so -Wl,-no-undefined two.cpp  $ g++ -shared -fpic -o libone.so -Wl,-no-undefined one.cpp  -ltwo -L. -Wl,-rpath,. $ g++ test.cpp -ldl $  ./a.out